# My Android Studio app is not removing contacts

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a contact list app that allows to not only add contacts, but to remove them as well. The problem is, once I press on the remove button, it crashes the app.

I get this error in the logs when I try to remove a contact:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.wolfix, PID: 6752
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts from pid=6752, uid=10154 requires android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithOperationApplicationExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:599)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:576)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:564)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:2196)
        at com.app.wolfix.Remove_Contact.deleteContact(Remove_Contact.java:43)
        at com.app.wolfix.Main_Remove_Contact.deleteContacts(Main_Remove_Contact.java:61)
        at com.app.wolfix.Main_Remove_Contact.onOptionsItemSelected(Main_Remove_Contact.java:46)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4269)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:384)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:228)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:65)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:207)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:779)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:975)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:623)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**with this code in particular not being part of the source code:**

```
at com.app.wolfix.Remove_Contact.deleteContact(Remove_Contact.java:43)
at com.app.wolfix.Main_Remove_Contact.deleteContacts(Main_Remove_Contact.java:61)
at com.app.wolfix.Main_Remove_Contact.onOptionsItemSelected(Main_Remove_Contact.java:46)
```

Here's the full code for these classes:

#### Remove_Contact:

```
public class Remove_Contact {

    public static Cursor getContactCursor(ContentResolver contactHelper, String startsWith){
        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        Cursor cur = null;
        try{
            if(startsWith != null && !startsWith.equals("")){
                cur = contactHelper.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " line \""
                        + startsWith + "%\"",null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " ASC");
            }else{
                cur = contactHelper.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,null,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
            }
            cur.moveToFirst();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cur;
    }

    public static void deleteContact(ContentResolver contactHelper, String number){
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(getContactID(contactHelper,number))};
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID+"=?",args).build());
        try{
            contactHelper.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,ops);
        }catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (OperationApplicationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static long getContactID(ContentResolver contactHelper, String number) {
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(number));
        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};
        Cursor cur = null;
        try{
            cur = contactHelper.query(contactUri,projection,null,null,null);
            if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                int personID = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID);
                return cur.getLong(personID);
            }
            return -1;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(cur != null){
                cur.close();
                cur = null;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

#### Main_Remove_Contact:

```
public class Main_Remove_Contact extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ListView listView;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    int PERMISSION_READ_WRITE_CONTACTS = 1000;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_refresh:
                showContacts();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_check:
                for(int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
                    listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                deleteContacts();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void deleteContacts() {
        Cursor phones = null;
        SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for(int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++){
            if(checked.valueAt(i) == true){
                phones = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(i);
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                Remove_Contact.deleteContact(getContentResolver(), phoneNumber);
            }
        }
        phones.close();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact(s) deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_remove_contact);
        initView();

        if((checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
            },PERMISSION_READ_WRITE_CONTACTS);
        }else{
            showContacts();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_READ_WRITE_CONTACTS){
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                showContacts();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we cannot display your contacts.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void showContacts() {
        Cursor cursor = Remove_Contact.getContactCursor(getContentResolver(),"");
        String[] fields = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cursor, fields, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void initView() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Contact Remover");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what's preventing the app from removing/deleting contacts?

Comment: Did you declare `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>` in your Manifest?

Comment: you should also read up on using "Protection level: dangerous" permissions - in these cases you need to prompt the user at runtime if it's ok to use that permission.

Comment: I've declared that permission in the manifest, so that's not the reason for the error to occur, I'll try that other permission.

Comment: Ok, after adding `android:protectionLevel="dangerous"` to the manifest, it still stops working... I don't know really.